# Typescript include extension methods

Tags: typescript

I am building a project in Typescript using Atom as my text editor. I have atom-typescript installed, which is compiling my code to JavaScript automatically.

What I am attempting to do is define a new extension method on type string to determine if it is null or blank. I have a main file which exports a single function, and a mocha test attempting to verify it is all working. The issue I am running into is that mocha is throwing a type error:`String.isNullOrEmpty is not a function`

Here is my `stringExtensions.ts`:

```
interface StringConstructor {
  isNullOrEmpty(str: string): boolean;
}

String.isNullOrEmpty = function(str: string): boolean{
  return (!str || 0 === str.length);
}
```

In my `main.ts` I have the following code:

```
///<reference path="extensions/stringExtensions.ts"/>
export function checkForUpdate(){
  if(String.isNullOrEmpty(location)){
    /* Do Stuff */
  }
```

In `main.spec.ts`

```
import {checkForUpdate} from "../lib/update"
describe("test", ()=>{
  if("should do something", ()=>{
    checkForUpdate();
  })
})
```

If I copy my code from the extension file into the main file everything is working fine so I know this is a reference problem. Atom-typescript is throwing no errors, it is able to find the code just fine and everything looks good on its end.

What modifications do I need to make to have the reference work correctly. I am looking at the compiled JavaScript code and there is no import instruction from my reference command. Should there be?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that typescript is able to find the `isNullOrEmpty` definition because of the triple slash reference. However, the execution is not reaching the point where the function is being bound to `String`. i.e the line of code

```
String.isNullOrEmpty = ...
```

is not being executed which is why `String.isNullOrEmpty` is `undefined` when you try to call the function. To fix this you can simply add

```
import './<path-to-file>/stringExtensions.ts'
```

to your main.ts. The import will execute the code in `stringExtensions.ts` and the function should be available inside your `checkForUpdate` function.